# How to change the host name locally in bash

Tags: bash, ubuntu, ssh, gnome, openssh

I want to generate ssh public key using ssh-keygen with custom host name in it at the end of the file
.
How to change the host name locally in bash.

Comment: Isn't it simpler to edit the generated key files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just provide the `-C` flag, the stuff at the end of the file is only a comment, not used for anything else except differentiation.

`ssh-keygen -C "somecomment@somehostname"`

Answer (score 2):

The hostname at the end of the key file (id_rsa.pub) is just a comment.   You can change is with any editor.

or if you really want to do it from the command line:

```
   awk '{$3 = "myname@myhost.com"; print;}' id_rsa.pub > new_id_rsa.pub
```